# Running list of specs2 specifications from a single spec2s parent specification

Tags: intellij-idea, specs2

I am currently working on maven based scala project with a bunch of specs2 specification tests and am using Intellij 2020.2 and scala 2.12.10 with specs2 version 4.9.4

I am able to run each specification with no issues but am having issues running all tests sequentially using IntelliJ with beforeAll and afterAll not appearing to work as expected (but does work when run individually).

I was thinking of create a parent specification which creates a list of all children specifications and then executes them - hoping that way I have more control.

My 'children' specifications are using mutable.Specification and along the lines of:

```
class BookmarkSpecs2(implicit ec: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification
    with BeforeAfterAll
    with Matchers
    with FutureMatchers
    with EmbedMongod {

    val prefix = "mongodb"
    val database = "bcTest"
    val domain = "localhost"
    val port = 12340

sequential

    "Update items" should {
        "adding" in {
...
        }
    }
```

Note inclusion of class's variable `(implicit ec: ExecutionEnv)`

For my parent specification I have been trying:

```
import org.specs2.Specification
import org.specs2.concurrent.ExecutionEnv
import org.specs2.specification.core.SpecStructure

class AllTestsSpecs2(implicit ec: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification {

  def is: SpecStructure =  sequential ^ s2"""
    ${"bookmark"  ~ bm}
  """
  def bm = new BookmarkSpecs2()
}
```

When executing the specification via IntelliJ it shows:

```
Testing started at 10:36 AM ...
/opt/jdk/jdk8u265-b01/bin/java -javaagent:/home/colinbester/Projects/idea-IC-202.6397.94/lib/idea_rt.jar=46535:/home/colinbester/Projects/idea-IC-202.6397.94/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath ... org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.Specs2Runner -s com.besterdesigns.bc.rest.AllTestsSpecs2 -showProgressMessages true


Process finished with exit code 0
```

without actually running any of the children test.

Pretty sure I am missing something here and would appreciate nudge in right direction.

Comment: Can you try passing `all` as an argument? In Intellij you need to specify `-Dspecs2.all` as a Java argument. `all` will execute all the linked specifications in a parent specification.

Comment: You're a star, I was pulling my hair out - that solved my problem.

Comment: Great, I turned it into a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked specifications can be executed by passing the `all` argument (the list of available arguments is available [here](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.10.0/org.specs2.guide.ConsoleOutput.html)).

In IntelliJ specs2 properties need to be specified as Java system properties so you need to specify `-Dspecs2.all` in the IntelliJ run configuration.